# DI design challenge with class which creates instances

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I want to use Dependency Injection (DI) for one of my projects. I have written a basic DI lib which basically works as follows

```
let di = new DI();
di.register('screen', Screen);   // contract name, class ref
di.register('pixels', Pixels);
```

And you can create instances as follows:

```
let pixels = di.getInstance('pixels');
```

or with one addition parameter

```
let pixeks = di.getInstance('pixels', [arrayOfPixels]);
```

The problem I have now is with the Screen class:

```
export default class Screen() {
   getPixels() {
       // Get pixels from a canvas
       return new Pixels(pixels);
   }
}
```

the `Screen` class creates instances of `Pixels`. This is not in line with DI, so the question is how can I solve this in a correct way. If there is a design pattern that might help, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to dependency inject a factory/DI container:

```
export default class Screen() {
   constructor(di) {
       this._di = di;
   }

   getPixels() {
       // Get pixels from a canvas
       return this._di.getInstance('pixels', [pixels]);
   }
}
```

However: **don't overdo it.** DI is useful and necessary, however that doesn't mean you need to "soft code" *everything* and keep *everything* configurable into infinity. If your class is defined to return instances of another closely related class, and there's no real need for dependency injection because neither class needs any sort of "configuration" or may be replaced entirely, then simply forgo it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. The main reason for DI for me is to mock dependencies in my unit tests

Comment: Does `Pixels` *do* something that requires mocking? If so: yes, DI it. If not: again, don't overdo it.